# Picasa API - URL does not work with tags

Tags: java, web-services, api, picasa

I want to implement a WebService to access a PicasaPhotoAlbum. But I have following problem:
I have following URL:

```
URL feedUrl = new URL("https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/466601293793610730264/album/Testalbum?tag=Test");
```

This does not work. But when I delete "?tag=Test" and the URL looks like this:

```
URL feedUrl = new URL("https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/use/466601293793610730264/album/Testalbum");
```

the code works perfect. The thing is, I only want to have the pictures with a special tag. Can someone explain me why this does not work with "?tag=Test".

My whole code is (I use the picasa API version 2.0):

```
public class RaceDriverImport implements IRaceDriverService {
PicasawebService myService = new PicasawebService("TestIt");

public RaceDriverImport() throws AuthenticationException {
    myService.setUserCredentials("test.picasa@gmail.com", "99thisisabadpw77");
}

@Override
public List<RaceDriver> getRaceDrivers() throws IOException, ServiceException {
URL feedUrl = new URL("https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/466601293793610730264/album/Testalbum?tag=Test");

    AlbumFeed feed = myService.getFeed(feedUrl, AlbumFeed.class);

    for (PhotoEntry photo : feed.getPhotoEntries()) {
        System.out.println(photo.getTitle().getPlainText());
    }
    List<RaceDriver> drivers = null;
    return drivers;
}
```

Comment: What is the error? If an HTTP error code, what is it, what is its associated message?

Comment: The error is I get no photos, when I use the tag at the end of the URL. I also tried it in my browser and there it works.

Comment: Our Album Feed is null when we add paramters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not say which version you are using, but for version 2.0 you do it this way:

```
URL feedUrl = new URL("https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/466601293793610730264/album/Testalbum");

Query myQuery = new Query(feedUrl);
myQuery.setStringCustomParameter("kind", "photo");
myQuery.setStringCustomParameter("tag", "test");
```

etc..

Reference: https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java#SearchByTags

Comment: Yeah, I use the version 2.0.

Comment: Hey there, I am working with Michael Langhamer in the same project. Thanks for your answer, but it didn`t solve the issue. Our AlbumFeed still would be null with your code, when we add the paramters, even though if we acess the URL in the Browser it would work. Is there a possibility to filter the pictures due to their Tag, after we made the request? Since the request without parameters works fine.

Comment: You are doing a AlbumFeed feed = myService.query(myQuery, AlbumFeed.class)? (not using myService.getFeed(feedUrl, AlbumFeed.class))

Comment: I tried some code I had and it is failing for me too. Did a search and found this issue reported May 22, 2013...maybe it's a bug on their side?

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4596&thanks=4596&ts=1369244817

Comment: Ok, thx for your help. We solved the probelm on another way. We read all the pictures of the album and fiter the ones with the right tag. I know that's not a good solution, but the only which works. However, thanks for your help!